# Dynamic font size SCSS (no JS)

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a need for a pure SCSS/CSS solution to my problem.

There are JS solutions which I am currently using, however I want to discontinue using it as it has issues.

Essentially, I have a sports player profile page in which the surname of the player is set behind the player image. I would like this name to take up 100% of the container width, simple.

The issue comes from the page being dynamic with player details being passed from the BE and the font size needs to scale according to the length of the player name while maintaining 100% width.

Is this even possible in pure SCSS/CSS? The text will be a child of CSS Grid if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

```
    <section>
      <h1>jordan</h1>
      <img src="https://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/5/Michael-Jordan.png" alt="Jordan" />
    </section>
```

```
    section {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    h1 {
      grid-column: 1/-1;
      grid-row: 1/-1;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: red;
      font-size: 24vw;
    }
    
    img {
      grid-column: 1/-1;
      grid-row: 1/-1;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1nqsemg9/7/

Edited to present example.

In this specific example, I have added a font size relevant to produce the required result. Will face issues with a different name.

Comment: Please include just enough code for us to be able to see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: that's not possible with CSS or SCSS. There are units relative to the viewport size like vw and vh which you can use for font-size, but you won't be able to determine a word's length with those. If you need it, use http://fittextjs.com/ (yes, that's JS, but easy to handle)

Comment: CSS clamp() might help, but if you want the text to be flexible check what Johannes suggestion the fittextjs.